# what is the function of createDM() method for user?

Tags: discord.js

this is my first time making a discord bot, and i was trying to welcome a person whenever they join the server by having the bot DM them.

what does the function createDM() do?

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) and if you have any other questions about Discord.js you can also ask on their personal Discord server. They even have a channel called "Newbie questions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`User.createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) and [`GuildMember.createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=createDM) return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) resolving with a new [DMChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel) between the client and the User/GuildMember.

An easier way to send a DM is to simply use [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) or [`GuildMember.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send), which implicitly create the channel for you. For example...

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.send('Hello!')
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

member.send is not a function
не работает так

```
      client.on('messageCreate', member => {
        if(member.content == "k") {
        member.send('Hello!')
          .catch(console.error);
        }
      });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).